Terraform Upgrade Error: AccessDenied 403 During Route53 GetHostedZone
So I paused my upgrade from 0.11.15 to 0.12.31 because, halfway through the upgrade process, I got this error:

Error: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::121212121212:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_e9ff994d3fa76329/user is not authorized to access this resource
status code: 403, request id: 37fc48e4-3b89-41fd-a1cf-da8418a18d67

I enabled debug mode during the plan with TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform plan
2024-06-12T12:06:36.668+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: 2024/06/12 12:06:36 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response route53/GetHostedZone Details:
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: Connection: close
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: Content-Length: 411
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: Content-Type: text/xml
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2024 02:36:36 GMT
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: X-Amzn-Requestid: 37fc48e4-3b89-41fd-a1cf-da8418a18d67
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: 
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: 
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: 2024/06/12 12:06:36 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0"?>
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>User: arn:aws:sts::121212121212:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_e9ff994d3fa76329/user is not authorized to access this resource</Message></Error><RequestId>37fc48e4-3b89-41fd-a1cf-da8418a18d67</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4: 2024/06/12 12:06:36 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response route53/GetHostedZone failed, attempt 0/25, error AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::121212121212:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_e9ff994d3fa76329/user is not authorized to access this resource
2024-06-12T12:06:36.781+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.50.0_x4:  status code: 403, request id: 37fc48e4-3b89-41fd-a1cf-da8418a18d67

I thought it might be an AWS provider bug, so I tried versions v2.50.0, v2.70.0, and v2.70.4 but still had no luck.
I don't get this 403 error on Terraform 0.11.15.
To add more context, our Route53 records are in a different AWS profile.
    provider "aws" {
      profile = "testing"
      region  = "ap-southeast-2"
      version = "v2.70.0"
    }
    
    provider "aws" {
      alias   = "us-east-1"
      profile = "testing"
      region  = "us-east-1"
      version = "v2.70.0"
    }
    
    provider "aws" {
      profile = "test"
      region  = "ap-southeast-2"
      alias   = "route53_company_net"
      version = "v2.70.0"
    }

this is how it is defined on the dns.tf file
resource "aws_route53_record" "countryconnect" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  name    = "au01-connect-testing.${var.domain}"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = module.cloudfront_api.domain_name
    zone_id                = module.cloudfront_api.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
  provider = aws.route53_company_net
}


our Route53 DNS records are in aws.route53_company_net provider

How are you defining the profile? Can you add that to the question?

i've just fixed it today, made a silly mistake, I thought terraform 0.12upgrade would check everything for me.
When I double check all my Route53 resources, I found that one of the records had no provider attached to it.
